# Bitbucket issue tracker in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, bitbucket, issue-tracking

I want to link Tasks to our Bitbucket server. However, when I try to add the server (`Tools > Tasks & Content > Configure servers`), it wants me to choose a server type.

**Q1.** I have no idea what type to select. I haven't found any reference for this question.

**Q2.** If a type is chosen, it asks for the server url. Do I need just `https://bitbucket.org` or do I need something more specific?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Tools > Tasks & Content > Configure servers
```

Add Server type `Generic`

**Tab: General**

Server URL: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/`*YOUR LOGIN*`/`*REPO_NAME*`

Fill `Username` & `Password`

Put a tick in the `Use HTTP authentication`

**Tab: Commit message**

`{summary} #{id}` - When commiting ID will be set tasks

**Tab: Server Configuration**

Tasks List URL: `{serverUrl}/issues?status=new&status=open`

Single Task URL: `{serverUrl}/issues/{id}`

Response Type : `JSON`

and then fill the data as shown is not the screenshot
[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4wsJ.png)

Comment: it 'works', thanks. But I get a list of my commits, not of my tasks (which would be empty at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need!

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the accepted answer, please note that version 2.0 of the Bitbucket API uses a different format for parameters noted here: [Bitbucket API 2.0: Filter and sort API objects](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/filtering)

The Task List URL should be: `{serverUrl}/issues?q=%28state+%3D+%22new%22+OR+state+%3D+%22open%22%29`

Comment: The accepted question and this correction work nice!